Is there a continuity between sublevel sets of a convex function?
this is a bit of an open ended question.
I have been thinking about the relationship between convexity and continuity of sublevel sets but couldn't find much about it. So I appreciate any thoughts, examples, ideas, opinions, references, etc.
Consider $f: \mathbb{R}^d \to [0,\infty)$ and denote by $S_f(c)$ the set $\{x : f(x) \leq c\}$.
Question 1: Suppose $f$ is continuous, convex and coercive.  Given $\epsilon>0$  is it true that there exists $\delta >0$ such that $$|c-c'| < \delta \Rightarrow |m(S_f(c)) - m(S_f(c')) |< \epsilon$$
where $m$ is the Lebesgue measure. The reason behind the coercivity assumption is that I want to keep the sublevel sets compact and the reason behind the convexity assumption is that without it you could build a counterexample like below:

Question 2: Given a positive real number $C$ can you always find $c \in Im(f)$ for which you have $m(S_f(c)) = C$? For this to be true I think convexity+coercivity will not be sufficient, you need now strict convexity+coercivity because it avoids a function having a "very large flat part" at the bottom, large enough to have $m(S_f(0))>C$.

Question 3: The strict convexity seems too strong. Maybe it could be replaced for a condition like $m(\{x : f(x) = c\})=0$ for every $c\in Im(f)$ along with coercivity. But I am not sure whether this condition is better than strict convexity or equivalent to it. I could not see think of counterexamples.

Question 1: The answer is yes. First, suppose $c < c'$ and let $x \in \big(\textrm{int} \, S_f(c')\big) \setminus S_f(c)$, and let $y \in S_f(c)$.  Let $L$ denote the line in $\mathbb{R}^d$ connecting $x$ and $y$; since $x \in \textrm{int}\, S_f(c')$, there exists some $z \in S_f(c') \cap L$ on the other side of $y$ from $x$, hence there exists $\alpha \in (0,1)$ such that:
$$
x = \alpha y + (1-\alpha)z,
$$
and by convexity of $f$,
$$
f(x) \le \alpha f(y) + (1-\alpha)f(z) \le \alpha c + (1-\alpha) c' < c'.
$$
Thus $c < f(x) < c'$. Consider now some strictly increasing sequence $c_n \nearrow c'$. We've then shown that for every $x \in \textrm{int}\, S_f(c')$, $x$ is eventually contained in some $S_f(c_n)$, as if not, the above would imply $c_n < f(x) < c'$ for all $n$, and hence that $c_n \not \to c'$.
Let's now use the sequential notion of continuity. Suppose $c_n \to c$; we wish to show $m\big(S_f(c_n)\big) \to m\big(S_f(c)\big)$. To establish this, it suffices to establish the claim for monotone sequences $c_n \nearrow c$ and $c_n \searrow c$.  By the preceding paragraph, if $c_n \nearrow c$, then:
$$
\bigcup_{n=1}^\infty S_f(c_n) = S_f(c)
$$
and clearly $S_f(c_n)$ is $\subseteq$-monotone, hence by continuity from below of the Lebesgue measure, we obtain $\lim_n m\big(S_f(c_n)\big) = m\big(S_f(c)\big)$.  If instead $c_n \searrow c$, then analogously:
$$
\bigcap_{n=1}^\infty S_f(c_n) = S_f(c)
$$
and by appeal to continuity from above of $m$, we obtain the desired result.
Question 2: The answer is no, as your counterexample indicates.
Question 3: Suppose we only have convexity and coercivity. One condition you might add that is weaker than strict convexity is to ask that the set of global minimizers be lower dimensional. This ensures that if $\underline{c}$ is the global minimum value of $f$, that $m(S_f(\underline{c})) = 0$. You could ensure this, for example, by asking that, for all $x \in \mathbb{R}^d$ for all $\varepsilon > 0$, there exists some $\|x' - x\| < \varepsilon$ such that $f(x) < f(x')$.
